# AI Search Program Doesn’t Output Search Matrix

Tags: python, search, artificial-intelligence

Wrote and ran an AI search program to run a search from start until the end or result is found. However, when I run it, I do not get the search result instead I get fail and none. Any idea what could be the cause of the issue would be much appreciated

---

```html
grid = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
init = [0, 0]
goal = [len(grid)-1, len(grid[0])-1]
cost = 1

delta = [[-1, 0], # go up
         [ 0,-1], # go left
         [ 1, 0], # go down
         [ 0, 1]] # go right

delta_name = ['^', '<', 'v', '>']

def search():
    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in  range(len(grid))]
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1 
    
    x = init[0]
    y =init[1]
    g = 0
   
    
    open = [[g, x, y]]
    
    found = False 
    resign  = False
    
    while found is False and resign is False:
        if len(open) == 0:
            resign = True
            print 'fail'
            
        else:
            open.sort()
            open.reverse()
            next = open.pop()
            
            x = next[3]
            y = next[4]
            g = next[1]
           
            
            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = next
                print next
            else:
                for i in range(len(delta)):
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >= 0 and y2 < len(grid):
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g + cost
                            
                            open.append([g2, x2, y2])
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
print search()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is in this part of the code:

```
x = next[3]
y = next[4]
g = next[1]
```

Every element in the `open` list only has three entries, so `3` and `4` are invalid indices. This should probably be changed to:

```
x = next[1]
y = next[2]
g = next[0]
```

---

A second issue is in the first line of this part:

```
if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >= 0 and y2 < len(grid):
    if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
        g2 = g + cost
```

Both `x2` and `y2` are compared to `len(grid)`, but you don't appear to have a square grid so one of those checks is going to be incorrect. It should probably be changed to:

```
if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >= 0 and y2 < len(grid[0]):
    if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
        g2 = g + cost
```

---

A potential third issue is that the intention appears to be for the `search()` function to return something, but it doesn't have any `return` statement. It will automatically always just return `None` then, which means that the `print search()` statement at the bottom is *always* simply going to print `None`. It is not clear from your question what you want the function to return, so I can't tell for sure how to fix it.

---

It may also be useful to observe that either the comments in this part are confusing:

```
delta = [[-1, 0], # go up
         [ 0,-1], # go left
         [ 1, 0], # go down
         [ 0, 1]] # go right
```

or the use of variable names such as `x` and `y` for coordinates is confusing. Not a problem in a technical sense, but in this implementation the `x` coordinates are modified by the entries with comments saying "go up" and "go down", whereas `y` coordinates are modified by "go left" and "go right".

Comment: Thanks for the prompt support, it is now working as expected. The indexes selected in the first part of code were using incorrect index I forgot to update these and the changes you suggested for the grid in the second part of the code worked well. I now get my expected result of [11, 4, 5] which is the g x and y values when my search is completed. Also the third confusing part, is just how movement is defined in the my defined grid environment cheers